# MissingMethodException - org.neo4j.kernel.impl.coreapi.schema.IndexDefinitionImpl.createNode() - Groovy

Tags: java, groovy, neo4j

I'm actually stuck on this for several hours..

My code is simple and just want to add several nodes using Labeled index. 
Without index stuff (Don't creating createDeferredSchemaIndex ) the code works without a problem.

My exception is:

```
groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method: org.neo4j.kernel.impl.coreapi.schema.IndexDefinitionImpl.createNode() is applicable for argument types: (java.util.LinkedHashMap, [Lorg.neo4j.graphdb.Label;) values: [[tag:START], [MacMorphoTag]]
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.ScriptBytecodeAdapter.unwrap(ScriptBytecodeAdapter.java:56)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PojoMetaClassSite.call(PojoMetaClassSite.java:46)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:45)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:108)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:120)
    at NextGenBatchInserterWithId$_run_closure1.doCall(NextGenBatchInserterWithId.groovy:110)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedMethod.invoke(CachedMethod.java:90)
    at groovy.lang.MetaMethod.doMethodInvoke(MetaMethod.java:324)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.metaclass.ClosureMetaClass.invokeMethod(ClosureMetaClass.java:278)
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1016)
    at groovy.lang.Closure.call(Closure.java:423)
    at groovy.lang.Closure.call(Closure.java:439)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.DefaultGroovyMethods.callClosureForLine(DefaultGroovyMethods.java:4281)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.IOGroovyMethods.eachLine(IOGroovyMethods.java:466)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.ResourceGroovyMethods.eachLine(ResourceGroovyMethods.java:288)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.ResourceGroovyMethods.eachLine(ResourceGroovyMethods.java:253)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.dgm$797.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PojoMetaMethodSite$PojoMetaMethodSiteNoUnwrapNoCoerce.invoke(PojoMetaMethodSite.java:271)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PojoMetaMethodSite.call(PojoMetaMethodSite.java:53)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:45)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:108)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:120)
    at NextGenBatchInserterWithId.run(NextGenBatchInserterWithId.groovy:71)
    at groovy.lang.GroovyShell.runScriptOrMainOrTestOrRunnable(GroovyShell.java:258)
    at groovy.lang.GroovyShell.run(GroovyShell.java:502)
    at groovy.lang.GroovyShell.run(GroovyShell.java:491)
    at groovy.ui.GroovyMain.processOnce(GroovyMain.java:650)
    at groovy.ui.GroovyMain.run(GroovyMain.java:381)
    at groovy.ui.GroovyMain.process(GroovyMain.java:367)
    at groovy.ui.GroovyMain.processArgs(GroovyMain.java:126)
    at groovy.ui.GroovyMain.main(GroovyMain.java:106)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.tools.GroovyStarter.rootLoader(GroovyStarter.java:106)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.tools.GroovyStarter.main(GroovyStarter.java:128)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:134)
Caught: groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method: org.neo4j.kernel.impl.coreapi.schema.IndexDefinitionImpl.shutdown() is applicable for argument types: () values: []
groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method: org.neo4j.kernel.impl.coreapi.schema.IndexDefinitionImpl.shutdown() is applicable for argument types: () values: []
    at NextGenBatchInserterWithId.run(NextGenBatchInserterWithId.groovy:182)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:134)
```

I know about the signature method that don't match with my parameters but, by the Neo4J code from here: https://github.com/neo4j/neo4j/blob/master/community/kernel/src/main/java/org/neo4j/unsafe/batchinsert/BatchInserterImpl.java 
 On line 578:
    public long createNode( Map properties, Label... labels )

That's exactly what I send from my groovy.

```
batch = org.neo4j.unsafe.batchinsert.BatchInserters.inserter(store,config)
batch = batch.createDeferredSchemaIndex( macMorphoTagLabel ).on( 'tag' ).create();
...

Label macMorphoTagLabel = DynamicLabel.label( 'MacMorphoTag' );

def Label[] macMorphoTagArray = [macMorphoTagLabel]
if (!tags[previousWordTag.macMorphoTag]) {
                        tags[previousWordTag.macMorphoTag] = batch.createNode([tag: previousWordTag.macMorphoTag], macMorphoTagArray)
                    }
```

What I missing here? I'm using Groovy 2.3.7 + Neo4j 2.1.5

For instance -> My full code: http://pastebin.com/Z98tMDYi problem happen on line 110

My Json file is: http://pastebin.com/xSxZd4ke (as UTF-8 file)

Comment: Can you try `batch.createNode(*macMorphoTagArray, tag: previousWordTag.macMorphoTag)`

Comment: No luck with this, got `groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method: org.neo4j.kernel.impl.coreapi.schema.IndexDefinitionImpl.createNode() is applicable for argument types: (java.util.LinkedHashMap, org.neo4j.graphdb.DynamicLabel) values: [[tag:START], MacMorphoTag]
 at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.ScriptBytecodeAdapter.unwrap(ScriptBytecodeAdapter.java:56)
 at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PojoMetaClassSite.call(PojoMetaClassSite.java:46)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In line 66 you're reassigning the `batch` variable. Replace

```
batch = batch.createDeferredSchemaIndex( macMorphoTagLabel ).on( 'tag' ).create();
```

with

```
batch.createDeferredSchemaIndex( macMorphoTagLabel ).on( 'tag' ).create();
```

Comment: Perfect! That's the problem. I followed an old question from here that used several batch variables but not checked about the method return.. shame on me. Another quick help, if you saw my createNode code, I'm actually set my own ID to the node, just to have the correct ID on the node that handle an array of triples. It's taking a lot of time (10x slower than without my ID) to execute.. is it a bad practice?

Comment: the id you're supplying is basically the position in the store file. If you use random longs, the files gets *huge*. Best practice is to either use sequential numbers or rely on the ids returned from createNode with passing one in.

Comment: Since on my problem the data is inserted at once, and I'm using the a long variable with auto increment, seems fine. I'm just getting too many relationships with my approach of data : One node - Word that points to node Group with an array of values (always 3) that points to 3 nodes of tags(by Node ID from array). And the groups has TO and FROM relationships.. I need to think more about it.. a 33MB text file is now a 150MB+ of database 127 just for relationships.. o.O It makes the queries awful.

Comment: I'm just wondering that the index stuff with my real deal file is not happening on time. After the insert I made a query using a label schema index and took 4 minutes. `MATCH (word:Palavra { word: 'Jersei' }) return word`